# How do I get Firebase to tell me the exact line of code a user crashed at?

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics

[image]

Look at these crash reports for my android app. Most of them either give me something useless like it crashed at line 1 or 3, or it gives no line at all. Is this how Firebase is supposed to work?

Comment: Why downvote? Isn't this question coding related? :(

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Comment: I have this written under release in gradle `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'`

Comment: Is there anything like this:
`minifyEnabled true`

Comment: Yes that's written too

Comment: Ok, maybe I can help you, give me some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Proguard try this workaround:

There will be a file named **proguard-rules.pro** in your **Gradle Scripts** section on Android Studio/ or in app folder of your project in your explorer.

In this file uncomment this line:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

This will keep your ClassName and line Number OK.

If you want to hide your className uncomment this line too.

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

And also write this line at last

```
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

This line will generate a **mapping.txt** file (which you can find in the app folder) to deobfuscate your stack trace when you publish the app in the playstore.

After doing all this, create a new release build of your app and update your existing build. Your crash report should work fine now.

If your app is available in the play store, with the apk you need to upload the generated **mapping.txt** file also. (If you are uploading aab file you don't need to upload it)

To upload the mapping file in the new play console follow these steps:

- Go to Release/"App bundle explorer"
- Select the right artifact in the top right corner
- Open Downloads tab
- Scroll to the Assests section
- Next to the "ReTrace mapping file" there should be an upload Button

This should work.

Comment: Thanks. Does this have any negative effects like less security? I can already tell the aab is 15% larger.

Comment: No, it doesn’t affect app security, it’s just for printing stack traces with valid line number. And aab is a format which distributes apk according to the devices, and it lessens the size of the apk (you can notice once you uploaded the aab).

Comment: Ok and I don't have to give any attention at all to that mapping.txt file if I'm uploading an aab file?

Comment: Yes, but you must print it by writing this `-printmapping mapping.txt` in your proguard file

Comment: Why should I print it if it's not needed?

Comment: It is needed if you use Proguard in your app. The only difference is: When you upload aab it automatically detects the mapping file and upload it, but in apk you have to upload it manually with every release